# UIautomator do not display classname while identifying object for appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to identify the object for Android automation using uiautomatorviewer while capturing object, I found that object class name is not displaying.

Please find the below version details:

- Appium: 1.9.1
- Device or emulator: both
- Desktop OS: mac
- Android OS: API Level 26 Android 8 (emulator) and  Android 7.0
- App built on : RN ^0.57.1

Please find the attached image for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android OS: API Level 26 **Android 8** (emulator) and **Android 7.0**

If you are using Appium with Android 6+ then you are using UIAutomation2 and have to use [Appium-Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases) for elements inspection

UIAutomatorviewer is not good choice anyway as XML representation in UIAutomation and UIAutomation2 **may be different**

Comment: It has been identified as the issue in appium https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11513 Looks like this change in RN library cause the problem https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/fa6035bda6c606868977179534cb941f26fbdb9

Comment: RN reported issue :: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21725

Comment: Actually I suggest to use content-desc values (you can set it as accessibility ids in RN app), but not class values which anyway will be repeated